# How do I dynamically create a hyperlink in asp c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I don't have code for this, as everything I have checked does not help me.

I am merely asking whether it's possible to do what I am trying to do.

I am creating a news article website. On the create page, on button click to create, a new aspx page is generated.

"Project/Articles/(todays date folder)/newarticle.aspx" is the generated path.

The create page is "Project/Create.aspx"

What I am trying to do is create a link to the newly generated article on the homepage.

"Projects/HomePage.aspx"

I want to know if it is possible to do this, even if I need to use Javascript/jquery for it.

I've gone through dozens upon dozens of help articles and forums to find my answer, but the best I could find is generating a link on the same page.

All of this is done with webforms.

Comment: You can create *.html files, obviously, but you cannot create aspx files, since they are compiled with a backend aspx.cs page - why not just use MVC instead of WebForms?

Comment: I created the aspx.cs along with it. The designer.aspx.cs was created on it's own.